# Hide one activity and show another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I've created an item - `activity2` in menu(in `res>menu>main.xml`) and I want when the user will click the `activity2`, `activity1` will hide (which is already running) and `activity2` will show.
And also when user press back the `activity2` will hide and `activity1` will visible to the user. 
  How to do this? Please explain.

Comment: Include your main.xml here, and also possibly the activity class

Comment: you want go activity2 in button click?

Comment: I'm using my mobile right now but i'll post it later. It just a simple app which has a webview in activity1(or you can call main activity) & in activity1 there is a menu item 'activity2'. And it also have a activity2.xml.

Comment: No in the menus there is a item 'activity2' not button(menus have settings item by default.' activity2 is just another item in menus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get onclick event of menu item in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.activity2:
            // start your activity2
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
            // no need to finish MainActivity 

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

- Now the `MainActivity` is not destroyed so if u press back on `Activity2` then `MainActivity` will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `menuItem.setVisible(false);` to hide menuItem tha maintain its visibility,

### EX :

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.icon_websearch);//your icon
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: R.id.action_websearch  what's this mean? Sorry I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onPrepareOptionMenu method in your Activity where in you can set visibility using setVisible. you can refer below code as an example:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem register = menu.findItem(R.id.menuregistrar);      
    if(userRegistered) 
    {           
        register.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        register.setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;
}
```